# simple-html-dom::restore_noise to parse an on-page javascript

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I am trying to parse some a javascript on this page:
http://www.chrystals.co.im/residential/Ramsey/House/Gardeners-Lane-Ramsey1117/view-map/1117

However, when parsing the dom, simple_html_dom removes what it considers noise and hence does not allow me to get the inner text of the script tags.

There seems to be a function to restore this noise, although it is not documented, called restore_noise.

It doesn't seem to have any effect. I have tried restoring the noise on the whole page:

```
$mappage = simple_html_dom::restore_noise($mappage);
```

and in the parsing loop:

```
$url = http://www.chrystals.co.im/residential/Ramsey/House/Gardeners-Lane-Ramsey1117/view-map/1117
$mappage = file_get_html($url);                         
                    foreach($mappage->find('script[!src]') as $s) {
                        $s = simple_html_dom::restore_noise($s);
                        $x = $s->plaintext;
                    }
```

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Gave up with the simple_html_dom approach in the end and just used some old fashioned preg_matching!

```
            $viewoptions = $detail->find('h4.view-options',0);
            foreach($viewoptions->find('a') as $element) {
                if(preg_match('/view-map/', $element->href)){
                    $mapurl = $baseurl.$element->href;
                    $item['mapurl'] = $mapurl;
                    $mappage = file_get_contents($mapurl);
                    $pattern = '/_geocoder_addMarker\(.*[0-9]\.[0-9]*/';                        
                    preg_match($pattern, $mappage, $matches);
                    $pattern = '/_geocoder_addMarker\(/';
                    $latlng = preg_replace($pattern,"" ,$matches[0]);
                    $latlng = explode(",", $latlng);
                    $item['lat'] = $latlng[0];
                    $item['lng'] = $latlng[1];
                } 
            }
```

Not being a great regex specialist, I found this site which helped me enormously:

http://www.phpliveregex.com/